# How to delete unused users after TFS2010 Migration-Upgrade from TFS2008

Tags: active-directory, migration, upgrade

I have a situation where after performing a migration-upgrade of our TFS2008 server to a new domain, I have a bunch of straggling users from the old domain that never created anything inside the 2008 server, nor need access anymore.

Does anyone know how do fully delete these old domain users from TFS2010 post-migration?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be more specific about "delete".  If they're in the `[SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users` group, simply remove them from the group, and they won't be able to connect anymore.

Comment: They are not associated with any group, but they show up when I list the users from the command line.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain what you mean by "list the users from the command line?"  Where are they showing in TFS, or are they only in AD?