# How to purge deleted AD users after TFS2010 Migration-Upgrade from TFS2005/TFS2008

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

```
TFSConfig Identities
====================================================================
Team Foundation Server Administration Log
Version  : 10.0.40219.339
System   : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (AMD64)
=============================================
Command: identities
Executing command Identities with 0 arguments.

Account Name        Exists (see note 1)  Matches (see note 2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXX\Administrator   True                 True                  
XXX\deleted_user    False                False
```

(1) The Exists column indicates whether the listed account exists in Windows.
   For the List mode of the command, this is the account stored in Team Foundation Server.
   For the Change mode, it is the target of the change.

(2) The Matches column indicates whether the SID stored in Team Foundation Server
   matches with Windows.

How do I purge **XXX\deleted_user**?
Searched, but nothing, except non-relavant:
[How to delete unused users after TFS2010 Migration-Upgrade from TFS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040510/how-to-delete-unused-users-after-tfs2010-migration-upgrade-from-tfs2008)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to accomplish the same thing as I have over 17,000 out 38,000 that can be removed. After some research I came across an answer to this question here: [Remove orphan identities in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042666/remove-orphan-identities-in-tfs-2010).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I saw that post and I think it’s irrelevant.
When user is deleted from MS AD, its SID is shown instead when we list permissions, membership, etc.
I’m fine with it.
BTW: Even tombstones in AD have their lifetime, and got garbage collected eventually.
Thinking about TFS non-existing uses as tombstones doesn’t help purging them at all.